# How to delete single field from the table in angularjs

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

My problem is,when im trying to delete single field from the table the entire fields are deleting..and after doing this my save button is not working when im trying to add a user,Please help me out..TIA.
    my code looks like:

```
            <html>
        <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        </head>
        <body ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="testController">
        <h1>Simple Example with Angular List with crude features</h1>
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr><th>Sr</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Action</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="user in userList track by $index">
                <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                <td>
                  {{user.Name}}
                </td>
                <td>{{user.Age}}</td>
                                        <td><div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" ng-click="edit($index);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" ng-click="delete();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
                        </div></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class="">
          <form class="form-horizontal">
           <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="test" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="userObject.Name"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <label for="age" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="test" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Age" ng-model="userObject.Age"/>
            </div>
          </div>
           <input type="hidden" ng-model="$scope.objectIndex" class="ng-valid">
          <div class="btn-group col-sm-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn" ng-click="save()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></i>Save</button>
                        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
        <script>
        angular.module('TestApp', ['TestApp.controllers']);

                        angular.module('TestApp.controllers', []).controller('testController', function($scope) {
                                        $scope.objectIndex = '';
                                        $scope.userList = [
                                                          {

                                                                          Name: 'Parvez Alam',
                                                                          Age: '28'
                                                          },

                                                         {
                                                                        Name: 'Sameer',
                                                                        Age: '13'
                                                          },
                                                          {
                                                                        Name: 'Rakesh',
                                                                        Age: '55'
                                                          },
                                                          {
                                                                        Name: 'Ramesh',
                                                                        Age: '44'
                                                          },
                                                          {
                                                                        Name: 'Aman',
                                                                        Age: '34'
                                                          },
                                                          {
                                                                        Name: 'John',
                                                                        Age: '23'
                                                          }
                                          ];

                                         $scope.edit = function(id) {
                                        //search user and update it
                                            $scope.objectIndex = id;
                                                        $scope.userObject = angular.copy($scope.userList[id]);
                                                        console.log($scope.objectIndex);
                                        }

                                        $scope.save = function() {
                                                        console.log($scope.objectIndex);
                                                        if($scope.userList[$scope.objectIndex] == null) {
                                                                        //if this is new record, add it in users array
                                                                        $scope.userList.push($scope.userObject);
                                                        } else {
                                                                        //for existing record, find this record using id
                                                                        //and update it.
                                                                                        $scope.userList[$scope.objectIndex] = $scope.userObject;
                                                        }

                                                        //clear the add record form
                                                        $scope.userObject = {};
                                                        $scope.objectIndex = '';
                                        }

                                        $scope.delete = function(id) {
                                                        //search record with given id and delete it
                                                        for(i in $scope.userList) {
                                                                        if($scope.userList[i].id == id) {
                                                                                        $scope.userList.splice(i,1);
                                                                                        $scope.userList = {};
                                                                        }
                                                        }

                                        }
                        });
        </script>
```

Comment: `delete($index)`??

Comment: Even i tried it, its not working still

Comment: Thank you so much,its working for me :)